# Rollback a set of actions in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a workflow like this as a Azure Logic App:

Read from Azure Table -> Process it in a Function -> Send Data to SQL Server -> Send an email

Currently we can check if the previous action ended with an error and based on that we do not execute any further steps.

Is it possible in Logic Apps to perform a Rollback of actions when one of the steps goes wrong? Meaning can we undo all the steps to the beginning when something in step 3 goes wrong, for example.

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no support for rollback in Logic Apps (as they are not transnational).

Note that Logic Apps provide out-of-the-box resiliency against intermittent errors (retry strategies), which should minimize execution failures.

You can add custom handling of errors (e.g. following your example, if something goes in step 3, you can explicitly handle the failure and add rollback steps). Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-exception-handling for details. You

Depending on whether steps in your logic app are idempotent you can also make use of the resubmit feature. It allows you to re-trigger the run with same trigger contents with which the original run instance was invoked. Take a look at https://www.codit.eu/blog/2017/02/logic-apps-resubmit-considerations/ for a good overview of this feature.